# <div> with "itemprop=text" contains ratingblock. Will this harm SEO?

Tags: seo, html5, microdata, schema.org

I am using WordPress and I am planning to use Schema.org to optimize the site for SEO. Because of WordPress’ structure, I am forced to put the `itemprop=text` on a `div`, containing both the whole content of the `article` (which is fine), but also a `div` which contains a *ratingblock* with thumbs …

Is this fine or not? Will this be a problem? I know it’s not optimal, but I guess I don’t have another choice. Example:

```html
<article id="post-29436" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemscope="">
<header>
<div class="post-entry" itemprop="text">
<div>
<div class="thumblock ">
<img of a thumb>
<img of a thumb>
<p>
content of postcontent of postcontent of postcontent of post
<p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`itemprop="description"` should only be used on descriptive texts, for example a product description. To use it elsewhere could be considered a spammy practice. I doubt you'd get penalised for it, but I'm guessing you will want to use the tags correctly. I believe that using them incorrectly won't result in the desired effect anyways. The whole point of using these tags is to tell search engines for example, what the data is meant for. Giving the entire `<article>` `itemprop="description"` would probably not be useful.

I do not understand what you mean with "because of Wordpress' structure". You can put whatever tag you want, on anything you want within the content area. Just use the code view. If it strips the tags after save, look into replacing TinyMCE with something else. A bit off topic but oh well.. :)

Comment: Well, it's not that simple to add a class on a wrapper contaning the `wp_content`. Anyhow, how come than that Yoast's site is using the exact same structure you are describing? He has an article with `itemprop="description`.

Comment: If you want to add the itemprop="description" to something outside the scope of what you can edit in the wordpress editor, then you'll have to do it in your theme files. I've looked through Yoast's site, and I can't find any itemprop="description" in the code... Paste the URL

Comment: True. It's itemprop="text" indeed. My fault :)

Comment: Okay so... does that fundamentally change this question? :)

Comment: No. Did I say that?

Comment: Can you paste some code so I can get a clearer picture of what you're after. I wanna be sure I've understood correctly.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: If you really can't put itemprop="text" on the <p> tag instead of the wrapping div, either don't use it or put itemprop="image" on each <img> within the <div class="thumblock">. the Schema is used to make search engines understand your site. As long as it makes complete sense to have images support the text, I don't foresee a problem. If the images are not supporting the text however, maybe consider putting them in an <aside>.

Comment: Shouldn't you change your question to be itemprop="text" instead of description?..